# How to get more detailed PHP errors from Webmatrix3 and IIS-Expres?

Tags: php, webmatrix, iis-express

I'm using WebMatrix 3 for some experimental sites I want to get up and running on my development machine as fast as possible.

I've switched the `php-ini` to the development version so I can see the errors I get, the problem is I've seen other people after having configured their `Apache` server get very nicely coloured and detailed errors like this:

[image]

While mine look like this:

[image]

Is there any settings I can modify or add-ons I can install to make my errors look more like those from Apache (I don't need the exact colour scheme but a coloured table and more info would be great) ?

Comment: That is how xdebug shows PHP error messages.

Comment: @CBroe I just looked it up and it should work with webmatrix : http://ruslany.net/2011/02/how-to-enable-xdebug-in-webmatrix/ so could you please reformulate this comment as a answer so I can chose it as the correct answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is how [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) shows PHP error messages.

For how to configure what is displayed exactly, see section “Stack Traces” here: http://xdebug.org/docs/all